# Error installing QGIS Open Layers plugin on 2.14 and 2.18

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin

When attempting to install the plugin Open Layers I get the following error

"Plugin installation failed:Failed to unzip the plugin package. Probably it's broken or missing from the repository. You may also want to make sure that you have write permission to the plugin directory: C:/Users/username/.qgis2/python/plugins"

I have confirmed that the user has write permissions to the directory and have also tried to manually install the plugin to the folder. This is on a windows 10 computer.The plugin will successfully install on another machine that is using windows 8.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? If so, what is the solution?

Comment: I installed this plugin now without any issues (" Probably it's broken or missing from the repository" is not true). So, try to install it running **QGIS** as Administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried that and came up with the same error.

Comment: So, I'm afraid that is your QGIS in windows 10 computer. Try to search questions where plugins issues are mentioned until solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was an imaging error in the computers drive. After the drive was reformatted the plugins install without the error.